# Can't delete Core Data entity from model editor

Tags: xcode, crash

I want to delete entity from Core Data model. For that i click on entity name and then click "Backspace". And xcode always get a crash. Xcode version: 10.1, macOS: Mojave. 10.14.4. Do you know another way to delete?

Comment: Actually i cant delete any...

Answer (score 0):

It was xcode bug, and after time its gonna out.